# Interupter brake lever compatible with hydraulic mechanical disk brakes?

Tags: disc-brake, interrupter-brakes

I have recently Installed JuinTech R1 Hydraulic mechanical pull disk brakes to my road bike. I would like to add some cyclo top or interrupter brake levers. Does anybody have any experience with this? Any issues?

[image]

Comment: Whats there to worry about? The brake can't know if its cable is being pulled by an interrupter lever or the original lever.

Comment: @Batman, I was told that these brakes require a relatively long pull. As I have never used interrupter levers, I was not sure if you can achieve the same length of pull on the interrupter as the main brake.

Comment: They're designed to work with normal / STI brake levers. Interrupter levers work just as well as normal brake levers -- the cable doesn't get pulled by an interrupter lever (it just moves a segment of housing). Extension levers (like you see on 70s bikes) cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

Those brakes are designed for cyclocross which means using STI "brifters" as you no doubt have on your bike.  Interrupter levers are also designed for use with STI levers.  The trio should be perfectly compatible.

One exception to the above would be if you had "mountain" brakes designed for MTB levers.  But that's not the case here.